# configuring vpn with strongswan

Tags: vpn

I need to do a vpn site-to-site, the company to integrate with gave me these params.

Gateway : 41.xxx.xx.xx

Host IP : 41.xxx.x.xx port xxxx

Transform set : esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac

Pre-shared key : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I have configured Strongswan http://www.strongswan.org. but unfortunately I CANT get it to work.

have anyone done this before? 
Thanks.

edited........................................
this is my auth.log

```
 May 11 21:23:52 li348-231 sshd[3000]: Connection closed by 58.108.232.7 [preauth]
May 11 21:24:05 li348-231 sshd[3012]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=60.173.14.143  user=root
May 11 21:24:07 li348-231 sshd[3012]: Failed password for root from 60.173.14.143 port 39095 ssh2
May 11 21:24:10 li348-231 sshd[3012]: Received disconnect from 60.173.14.143: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
May 11 21:24:13 li348-231 sshd[3015]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=60.173.14.143  user=root
May 11 21:24:15 li348-231 sshd[3015]: Failed password for root from 60.173.14.143 port 41129 ssh2
May 11 21:24:15 li348-231 sshd[3015]: Received disconnect from 60.173.14.143: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
May 11 21:25:01 li348-231 CRON[3018]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 11 21:25:01 li348-231 CRON[3018]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 11 21:26:21 li348-231 ipsec_starter[3021]: Starting strongSwan 5.1.2 IPsec [starter]...
May 11 21:26:21 li348-231 ipsec_starter[3040]: charon (3041) started after 20 ms
May 11 21:29:47 li348-231 ipsec_starter[3040]: charon stopped after 200 ms
May 11 21:29:47 li348-231 ipsec_starter[3040]: ipsec starter stopped
May 11 21:29:50 li348-231 ipsec_starter[3204]: Starting strongSwan 5.1.2 IPsec [starter]...
May 11 21:29:50 li348-231 ipsec_starter[3225]: charon (3226) started after 20 ms
May 11 21:35:01 li348-231 CRON[3310]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 11 21:35:01 li348-231 CRON[3310]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

edit to add the tail -f /var/log/syslog output

```
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for @blinks.com @ccxtnm.net 
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon test-vectors aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md4 md5 rdrand random nonce x509 revocation constraints pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pem openssl xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke updown eap-identity eap-mschapv2 addrblock
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 00[LIB] unable to load 5 plugin features (5 due to unmet dependencies)
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 10[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'net-net'
May 12 09:02:06 li348-231 charon: 10[CFG] added configuration 'net-net'
```

Comment: You need to provide more information to let someone help you. Can you provide logs from /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth.log? and what version of strongswan and ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hi Faisal, thanks for the concern.  this is my log from auth.log

Comment: There are only 4 entries related to strongswan (named 'charon') in this log data and they too are related to starting and stopping of the strongswan server.

You should run 'sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog' on your server and then try to connect to the VPN server. The 'tail -f' command will show you the new events being logged in the syslog . You are very likely to find the problem you are facing in those logs.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the logs generated by StrongSwan server so that people may help you. Here's how you can find the logs related to your issue:

1. Start VPN server using:

   ```
   sudo ipsec start
   ```
2. Once the VPN server is running, type the following command in your terminal to see what is happening on your machine:

   ```
   sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
   ```

   This  command lets you see events on your terminal as they are being logged into syslog.
3. Now try to connect from a VPN client. If the client can reach the server, you will see the events being logged in `syslog` under `charon` process. If you see nothing related to `charon`, it is most probably a network connectivity issue.
4. You can also use `sudo tail -x /var/log/syslog > debugfile` to dump the last `x` lines of syslog to `debugfile` for better analysis
5. Post those logs here if you are unable to identify the issue.